# random image on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random

I have found several scripts but i don't get them to work:
What am i doing wrong;

I want to change the color and some images on my page, so the second time you visite the page you may get another color.

I get the font color to change, but having problems with my image.

the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#D4FF00","#E18000","#ED4498","#0080C0"];
  var Rlogo= ['BIMP_groen.jpg','BIMP_oranje.jpg','BIMP_roze.jpg','BIMP_blauw.jpg'];  
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
  $('a').css("color", colors[rand]);
  $('h2').css("color", colors[rand]);
  $('<img src="images/logo/' + Rlogo[rand] + '">').appendTo('#logo');
  });
```

in my html i have;

```
<img src="images/logo/BIMP_oranje.jpg" id="logo" align="right" alt='align="right"'>
```

the image doesn;t change on refresh.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
$('<img src="images/logo/' + Rlogo[rand] + '">').appendTo('#logo');
```

with this:

```
$('#logo').attr("src","images/logo/" + Rlogo[rand]);
```

Essentially what this means is "get the DOM element with `id="logo"` and change the `"src"` element to `"images/logo/" + Rlogo[rand]`.

Comment: it is very strange and doesn't make sence...when i change the line also my font color changer doesn't work and the image doesn't change. This doesn't make sence...i will try it on an other computer

Answer (score 0):

"appendTo" add some content to an element but the #logo element ( which is an "img" element ) does not have inner html.

You should do something like this instead :

```
$("#logo").attr("src","images/logo/"+Rlogo[rand]);
```

Comment: it is very strange and doesn't make sence...when i change the line also my font color changer doesn't work and the image doesn't change. This doesn't make sence...i will try it on an other computer

Comment: Can you upload your web page, or post your entire code. I test it and it works so you might have missed something or maybe a synthax error. Does the javascript console shows you any error ?

Comment: I didn't have time to work on the page the last couple of days. I can't upload just yet, so i zipt the content and made them available for download: [link]http://www.screencast.com/t/zeCEImXx9 I don't now much about java so there will be some stupid data and some copy paste and it is a work in proces so be yentl.   Thanks for looking into it...if you delete the logo reference in the randomcolor.js the fonts change if you activate the line the fonts won't change

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the image in the logos parent element:

```
<div id="logoParent">
<img src="images/logo/BIMP_oranje.jpg" id="logo" align="right" alt='align="right"'/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#logoParent').html('<img src="images/logo/' + Rlogo[rand] + '"/>');
</script>
```

Comment: Note that changing the logo after the ready event, you might experience flickering, as the original logo image might show when the page is rendering. Consider picking the random logo on the server side, or include the script picking the logo immediately after the logo element to reduce the flickering effect, as shown in the example :)

Comment: doesn't wrok i posted my scripts in the anwser above